# Pyinstaller does not work with local files

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've made an app with PyQt5 and it works perfectly fine on my environment, and now I wan't to deploy it to .exe and .dmg with pyinstaller.

My app uses two local files certificate.yml and data.pkl which each contains certificate data for AWS and data. These are located in the same directory with main.py, which starts my app.

In my main.spec file I've added following

```
a.datas += [('certificate.yml', 'certificate.yml', 'DATA'),
            ('data.pkl', 'data.pkl', 'DATA')]
```

and made .app. However, when I start my .app, it does not find certificate.yml file and raise following error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'certificate.yml'
```

How can I include my local files with pyinstaller?

Comment: Are you ensure that you use `pyinstaller [options] <filename.spec>` and not `pyinstaller [options] <filename.py>`?

Comment: @Hiadore Yes I did use .spec

Comment: Okee.. Did you compile to one file (using --onefile or -F flag) or to folder?

Comment: @Hiadore I've tried both, using --onefile and default, but both didn't work.

Comment: @Hiadore I can give my github link if you want.

Comment: Ok, let me check the github. But I am on trip until Monday, may can check at Tuesday.

Comment: @Hiadore https://github.com/SeungsuKim/GetPaired this is my github link. Thank you for your help and I hope you take a great trip.